# Flag that indicates if Pycharm's is running the code with "Debug" or "Run"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I've been wanting to run something only when I use "Debug" in PyCharm and make the code avoid it when it is run using "Run".

I saw some references to the __debug__ variable but it doesn't seem to change value as long as I run my code in PyCharm. I've seen some other comments referring to -O which I think, refer to running the code outside of the IDE.

I'm looking at creating something like this

```
if variable:
    print("Debug mode")
else:
    print("Run mode")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would see if `sys.gettrace()` would work, like this:

```
import sys

if sys.gettrace() is None:
    print("Run Mode")
else: print("Debug Mode")
```

The documentation on `gettrace` is [HERE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.gettrace), and should work with most implementations/IDEs. I also use Pycharm (Community and Professional) and use this to separate debugging logic.

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm's debugger is merged with PyDev's, so you can use:

```
import sys

if "pydevd" in sys.modules: 
    print("Debug mode")
else:
    print("Run mode")
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Only goes into the else statement.

Comment: Huh weird, it works on PyCharm 2018.2.1 Professional Edition

Comment: So if you would click on the "Run" button it would pring "Run mode" and then "Debug mode" when you would click on the Debug button? I'm still quite green so I might be saying nonsense but would it be because you changed the run configurations? my PyCharm doesn't seem to detect "pydevd" in sys.modules. What is it supposed to be? it's just looking for a string ?

Comment: I only changed the theme to IntelliJ and the font size to 18. Which version are you using?

Comment: Hi HSK, I am using the latest version (auto-update is on from the JetBrains Toolbox application).